# Extract the id by validating the child element from the JSON response

Tags: jmeter

For the following response as a form of JSON, I want to extract a particular value on the validating first name.

```
{
    "system": false,
    "redirect": false,
    "url": "user",
    "infinite": false,
    "csrf": {
        "name": "csrf_token",
        "value": "1fc51ba92c87ad1f086195e36a4a6b02"
    },
    "version": "2.0.1869",
    "view": {
        "data": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "id": null,
                    "name": "No Workspace",
                    "users": [
                        {
                            "id": "170303",
                            "account_id": "143003",
                            "email": "Perfuser554@gmail.com",
                            "first_name": "Perf-WxC",
                            "last_name": "Eve-971"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "170318",
                            "account_id": "143003",
                            "user_type_id": "3",
                            "email": "Perfuser555@gmail.com",
                            "password_format": "1",
                            "first_name": "Perf-WMV",
                            "last_name": "Eve-972"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "170320",
                            "account_id": "143003",
                            "email": "Perfuser556@gmail.com",
                            "first_name": "Perf-YTC",
                            "last_name": "Eve-973"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "170321",
                            "account_id": "143003",
                            "email": "Perfuser557@gmail.com",
                            "first_name": "Perf-ZvF",
                            "last_name": "Eve-974"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "170322",
                            "account_id": "143003",
                            "email": "Perfuser558@gmail.com",
                            "first_name": "Perf-WmO",
                            "last_name": "Eve-975"
                        }
                    ],
                    "company_name": "Local host"
                }
            ]
        },
        "show_nav": true
    }
}
```

I want to extract the `id` and `account_id` for a particular user on the basis of `first name`. For example  for `Perf-YTC` the `id` is `170320` and `account_id`  is `143003`.

Could use the JSON extractor, but dont know the index value  mentioned in the image.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following as a JSON extractor,

`$..[?(@.first_name == "Perf-YTC")].id` for `id` and

`$..[?(@.first_name == "Perf-YTC")].account_id` for `account_id`

[image]

[image]